# Completable doesn't call onComplete or onError method in Subscribe

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, android-room

I have the following code:

```
    mCompositeDisposable.add(Observable.just(bundle)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(true))
            .map(_bundle -> new Movie(_bundle.getString(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME),
                    _bundle.getInt(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_WATCHERS),
                    _bundle.getString(MovieListFragment.EXTRA_IMAGE),
                    _bundle.getString(MovieListFragment.EXTRA_SLUG)))
            .flatMap(movieEntity -> MovieDatabase.getMovieDao().deleteMovie(movieEntity.getName()).toObservable())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(false))
            .subscribe(
                    result -> mView.onMovieDeleted(),
                    error -> {
                        mView.onMovieDeleteFailed();
                        Timber.e(error);
                    }
            )
    );
```

It should delete row from database and call ui method to notify about success or error completion. But in fact it deletes the row, but doesn't call any lambdas from `subscribe` method. So, what's the matter and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try debug the callbacks? What deos mView.onMovieDeleted(), do?

Comment: If `deleteMovie` is a `Completable`, there is no value to emit and `flatMap` ends with no items on its own. Therefore, the result -> lambda is not invoked. Add an onComplete handler instead.